# Como puedo dispensar billetes de diferentes denominaciones en C#?

Tags: c#

Hola estoy tratando de crear un programa que dispense la menor cantidad de billetes. Ejemplo:

Tengo la denominación de 200 y 1000, lo que quiere decir que si el usuario digita 600 se le debe indicar que se le entrego 3 billetes de 200, pero si ingresa 1600, debe indicarle que se le entrego 1 billete de 1000 y 3 de 200. Esta haciendo un método para esa validación pero no encuentro la lógica de como hacerlo.

Aquí el código de la validación que he hecho:

```
void entregaDeDinero(int cantidadDeRetiro)
{
    int entrega;

    if (cantidadDeRetiro >= billeteDociento || cantidadDeRetiro <=800)
    {
        entrega = cantidadDeRetiro / billeteDociento;
        Console.WriteLine("Usted retiro " + cantidadDeRetiro + " y se le entrego " + entrega + " billetes de " + billeteDociento +".");
        Console.ReadKey();

    } 
    else if(cantidadDeRetiro == 1000)
    {
        entrega = cantidadDeRetiro / billeteMil;
        Console.WriteLine("Usted retiro " + cantidadDeRetiro + " y se le entrego " + entrega + " billete de " + billeteMil + ".");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }            
}
```

Comment: Cuales son las denominaciones de billetes de las que dispones

Comment: entra aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506600/c%c3%b3mo-desglosar-cierta-cantidad-de-euros-en-billetes-y-monedas

Answer (score 0):

Agrego una solución recursiva, los comentarios están en el código.

```
public class Program
    {
         
        public static void Main()
        {
            // lista para guardar las tuplas de cantidad de billetes de una denominación y el 
            // valor de la denominación
            List<(int, int)> billetesEntregados = new List<(int, int)>();

            int cantidad = 1600;
            // llamar la función recursiva y pasarle la lista para que la vaya llenando
            EntregaDeDinero(cantidad, billetesEntregados);

            // impresión final
            Console.Write(string.Format("Usted retiró {0} y se le entregó: ", cantidad));
            billetesEntregados.ForEach(b =>
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} billetes de {1} ", b.Item1, b.Item2));
            });
        }

        public static void EntregaDeDinero(int cantidad, List<(int, int)> billetesEntregados)
        {
            // caso base termina la recursión
            if (cantidad == 0) return;

            int denominacionBillete = 0;

            // establecer la denominación del billete según la cantidad
            if (cantidad >= 1000)
            {
                denominacionBillete = 1000;
            }
            else
            if (cantidad >= 200)
            {
                denominacionBillete = 200;
            }
            // aquí se van agregando otras denominaciones menores
            // else if(){

            // }

            // calcular cuantos billetes de la denominacióna actual caben
            // en la cantidad
            int totalBilletes = cantidad / denominacionBillete;
            // agregar a la lista la cantidad de billetes de la denominación actual
            // y el valor de la denominación
            billetesEntregados.Add((totalBilletes, denominacionBillete));
            // paso recursivo, a la cantidad se le resta la cantidad cubierta con 
            // los billetes de la denominación actual
            EntregaDeDinero(cantidad - (totalBilletes * denominacionBillete), billetesEntregados);

            return;
        }

    }
```