# ¿Cómo desglosar cierta cantidad de euros en billetes y monedas?

Tags: c#, monedas

### **Esta pregunta es autorespondida**

Me gustaría compartir con la comunidad un algoritmo para desglosar cierta cantidad de euros en billetes y monedas utilizando para ello la menor cantidad posible de billetes y monedas.

Para esto hay que tener en cuenta que el euro tiene las siguientes denominaciones: **billete de 500 euros**, **billete de 200 euros**, **billete de 100 euros**, **billete de 50 euros**, **billete de 20 de euros**, **billete de 5 euros**, **moneda de 2 euros**, **moneda de 1 euro**.

**Nota:** No se tienen en cuenta los céntimos del euro, ya que la explicación se hace con cantidades de dinero que representan números naturales.

Atendiendo a esto si queremos desglosar la cantidad **534 euros**, esta quedaría expresada como:

**1 billete de 500 euros**

**1 billete de 20 euros**

**1 billete de 10 euros**

**2 monedas de 2 euros**

Comment: si en una lista se guardan las denominaciones, solo es necesario una unica iteracion sobre esa lista para imprimir los billetes y monedas utilizados, actualizando el valor  del dinero ingresado.

Comment: @LF publica tu respuesta y asi los usuarios tendran mas opciones ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de algoritmo es conocido como **algoritmo ávido**, **goloso**, **voraz** o **primero el mejor** y es muy utilizado en **Ciencias de la Computación** para resolver **problemas de optimización**.

A continuación el código:

```
using System.Collections;

static class Contabilidad
{
    static private readonly int[] denominaciones = { 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };

    static public IEnumerable DesgloseDeDinero(int dinero)
    {
        int desglose = 0;
        string euro = "";
        string resultado = "";

        if (dinero > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < denominaciones.Length; i++)
            {
                desglose = dinero / denominaciones[i];
                dinero = dinero % denominaciones[i];

                if (i < 7) //billetes
                {
                    if (desglose == 1)
                    {
                        resultado = string.Format("{0} billete de {1} euros", 1, denominaciones[i]);                           
                    }
                    else if (desglose > 1)
                    {
                        resultado = string.Format("{0} billetes de {1} euros", desglose, denominaciones[i]);
                    }
                }
                else //monedas
                {
                    euro = (i == 8) ? "euro" : "euros";

                    if (desglose == 1)
                    {
                        resultado = string.Format("{0} moneda de {1} {2}", 1, denominaciones[i], euro);
                    }
                    else if (desglose > 0)
                    {
                        resultado = string.Format("{0} monedas de {1} {2}", desglose, denominaciones[i], euro);
                    }
                }

                if (desglose != 0)
                {
                    yield return resultado;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para darle solución a esta problemática declaramos la **clase estática Contabilidad** y dentro de ella declaramos el método **estático y público DesgloseDeDinero**, este método retorna un **IEnumerable**, y se le pasa como parámetro un **int**, siendo este parámetro la cantidad
de dinero que se desglosará teniendo en cuenta las denominaciones de billetes y monedas del euro. Se declara también dentro de la clase el campo privado, estático y de solo lectura denominaciones, el cual es es un **arreglo de tipo int** que guardará todas las denominaciones del euro.

Dentro de este método se declaran las siguientes variables:

**1)** **desglose**: **variable de tipo int** que se usará para ir guardando la cantidad de billetes o monedas en que se irá desglosando la cantidad pasada como parámetro.

**2)** **euro**: **variable de tipo string** que se usará para almacenar las palabras "euros" o "euro", es decir guardará el plural o el singular.

**3)** **resultado**: **variable de tipo string** que servirá para retornar cada desglose individual que se hace de la cantidad de dinero pasada como parámetro.

Una vez declaradas las variables preguntamos si la cantidad de dinero recibida es mayor que **0**, de cumplirse esta condición entonces se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que recorrerá cada denominación del euro e irá dividiendo la cantidad de dinero pasada como parámetro por la denominación correspondiente en la iteración en curso.

Si el índice del **ciclo for** es menor que *7* (denominaciones de billete para **500**, **200**, **100**, **50**, **20**, **10**, **5 euros**) indica que se trata de un billete, entonces guardamos en la **variable resultado**, el texto correspondiente a ese billete. En caso de que el índice del **ciclo for** sea mayor o igual que **7** indica que estamos en presencia de una moneda (denominaciones de moneda para **2**, **1 euros**).

Por último se retorna el valor almacenado en la **variable resultado** utilizando la expresión:

```
yield return resultado;
```

**yield** es una **palabra clave** y se usa para devolver cada elemento de una colección de uno en uno, en este ejemplo no devolvemos una colección completa para recorrerla después con un **foreach**, sino que a medida que vamos obteniendo un desglose se "saldrá momentáneamente" de la función e imprimirá en pantalla este desglose, **yield** permite saber en que iteración nos quedamos y después de que se imprima en pantalla el desglose del momento, se "caerá" de nuevo en la función exactamente en el índice de iteración que nos quedamos.

Para usar la clase antes descrita hacemos:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Escriba un número: ");

        var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        foreach (var d in Contabilidad.DesgloseDeDinero(num))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d); 
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Aquí se llama a la **función DesgloseDeDinero** dentro de un **foreach** de forma tal que a medida que vayamos obteniendo cada desglose se imprima por pantalla, ya que con **yield** como se explicó anteriormente los desgloses se van imprimiendo de uno en uno.

Para ver mas información sobre el uso de **yield** vea: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Answer (score 0):

Tambien, utilizando las operaciones `divison entera` (`//`) y `residuo de la operacion` (`%`) se puede realizar en un unico bucle actualizando el valor ingresado.

Codigo Python:

```
b, m = "billetes", 'monedas'
denominaciones = (500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 5, 2, 1)
tipos = (b,b,b,b,b,b,m,m)
iterador = zip (denominaciones, tipos)

monto = ''
while not monto.isdigit():
  monto = input('Ingrese el monto a desglozar: ')
monto = int(monto)

for denominacion, tipo in iterador:
  if monto >= 0:
    num_objetos = monto//denominacion
    monto = monto%denominacion
    if num_objetos:
      rplc = {1: ''}.get(num_objetos,'s')
      print(f'{num_objetos} {tipo.replace("s", rplc)} de {denominacion} euros.')
```

cuya salida tambien da:

```
Ingrese el monto a desglozar: 531
1 billetes de 500 euros.
1 billetes de 20 euros.
2 billetes de 5 euros.
1 monedas de 1 euros.
```

y el tiempo de ejecucion resulta en

`1.66 ms ± 271 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: La pregunta es en C#, la respondiste en Python pero igual no importa

Comment: lo siento, no manejo lenguage `C#`. igual veo que tambien utilizaste los operadores `/` y `%` de manera recursiva, lo cual era justo lo que queria mostar

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es crear una estructura que tenga la lógica de las "Denominaciones"

```
public record Denominacion
{
    public static readonly Denominacion[] Denominaciones = {
        new Denominacion(500,TipoDenom.Billete),
        new Denominacion(200,TipoDenom.Billete),
        new Denominacion(100,TipoDenom.Billete),
        new Denominacion(50,TipoDenom.Billete),
        new Denominacion(20,TipoDenom.Billete),
        new Denominacion(10,TipoDenom.Billete),
        new Denominacion(5,TipoDenom.Moneda),
        new Denominacion(2,TipoDenom.Moneda),
    };

    public int Valor { get; set; } 
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public TipoDenom Tipo { get; set; }

    private Denominacion(int valor, TipoDenom tipo)
    {
        this.Valor = valor;
        this.Tipo = tipo;   
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Cantidad switch
        {
            0 => "",
            1 => $"{Cantidad} {Tipo} de {Valor} euros",
            _ => $"{Cantidad} {Tipo}s de {Valor} euros",
        };
    }

    public enum TipoDenom
    {
        Moneda, Billete
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Denominacion> DesgloseDeDinero(int dinero)
    {
        foreach (var d in Denominaciones)
        {
            int cantidad = dinero / d.Valor;
            if (cantidad == 0) continue;
            dinero = dinero - d.Valor * cantidad;
            yield return d with { Cantidad = cantidad };
        }
    }
}
```

Donde cada `Denominacion` tiene

- **Valor**: Indica la denominación del billete/moneda
- **Cantidad**: Indica cuantos billetas/monedas hay
- **Tipo**: Si es billete o moneda

Además tiene un array con las distintas denominaciones existentes ya seteadas y una función `ToString()` para convertir a texto

Finalmente una función `DesgloseDeDinero` que es la que realiza todo el calculo

Ejemplo de uso:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", Denominacion.DesgloseDeDinero(534)));
}
```

```
1 Billete de 500 euros
1 Billete de 20 euros
1 Billete de 10 euros
2 Monedas de 2 euros
```