# Desglosar billetera en C#

Tags: c#

Llevo varias semanas con un trabajo que me pide hacer un codigo que desglose una billetera en c#. Aquí está el error:

> Expected:
> Insert a quantity of money: 1 bills of 100, 0 bills of 50, 1 bills of 20, 1 bills of 10, 1 bills of 5, 1 coins of 2 and 0 coins of 1 are
> needed for this amount of money.
> Press any key. Got:
> Insert a quantity of money:
> 1.37 bills of 100, 0 bills of 50, 0 bills of 20, 0 bills of 5, 0 coins of 2 and 0 coins of 1 are needed for this amount of money.
> Press any key.

Aquí teneis el código:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaracion de variables
            double Dinero, B1 = 0, B2 = 0, B5 = 0, B10 = 0, B20 = 0, B50 = 0, B100 = 0;
            //Entrada de datos
            Console.Write("Insert a quantity of money: ");
            Dinero = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //Proceso
            if (Dinero >= 100)
                B100 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 100;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B100 * 100);
            if (Dinero >= 50)
                B50 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 50;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B100 * 50);
            if (Dinero >= 20)
                B100 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 20;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B20 * 20);
            if (Dinero >= 10)
                B10 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 10;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B10 * 10);
            if (Dinero >= 5)
                B5 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 5;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B5 * 5);
            if (Dinero >= 2)
                B2 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 2;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B2 * 2);
            if (Dinero >= 1)
                B1 = Math.Abs(Dinero) / 1;
            Dinero = Dinero - (B1 * 1);
            //Salida
            Console.WriteLine(B100 + " bills of 100, " + B50 + " bills of 50, " + B20 + " bills of 20, " + B5 + " bills of 5, " + B2 + " coins of 2 and " + B1 + " coins of 1 are needed for this amount of money.");
            Console.Write("Press any key.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Me parece haber visto esta pregunta hace algunos días y la marcaron como duplicada con esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/506600/301324 . Existe algún problema de esas respuestas que no te sirva??

Comment: si, tengo un problema, y es que en el código que se muestra en la otra pregunta, lo que hace es mostrar los tipos de billetes y monedas en lineas distintas y ademas, pone el numero que quiere desglosar en la consola. Yo lo que necesito, es que hacer un codigo que pida al usuario un numero y que lo desglose en billetes de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 y monedas de 2 y 1.

Comment: Pides tú número al usuario y lo pasas por la función, el resto es dar un poco de formato a la salida. Pero es exactamente lo mismo

Comment: @CapultaNT en la otra pregunta se hace exactamente lo que pides, analiza ese código y adaptalo a tus necesidades