# Calcular cantidad de billetes automáticamente c#

Tags: c#

Buenos días estoy realizando un programa de corte de venta en donde el empleado debe de ingresar los billetes que tiene, es decir, debe de ingresar cuantos billetes tiene de cada denominación y que se muestre la suma en dinero de cada cantidad. Cuanto suma en billetes de 1000, de 500 y así. Estoy intentando que se muestre la suma en automático, pero no he podido lograrlo, intente varias maneras y nada sigue en 0. La cantidad se ingresa en un textbox y se muestra el resultado en un label. ¿Hay manera de que esto se pueda realizar? Quiero que sea en automático sin tocar ninguna tecla solo al salir del click del textbox. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void lbt1000_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int c1, Ctotalc1 = 0;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox14.Text)) c1 = 0;
            else c1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox14.Text);
            Ctotalc1 = c1 * 1000;
            lbt1000.Text = Ctotalc1.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Saludos. Tu **if** está mal; quita la negación (**!**).

Comment: Que es lbt1000?? si es tu label de destino, entonces, ademas del error que te remarcaron, estas aplicando el evento al control equivocado... como se llama el control donde pones la cantidad??? a ese control tenes que aplicarle este evnto....

Comment: Entra aki: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506600/c%c3%b3mo-desglosar-cierta-cantidad-de-euros-en-billetes-y-monedas

Comment: Complicado sin saber a qué corresponde cada nombre

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo desglosar cierta cantidad de euros en billetes y monedas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506600/c%c3%b3mo-desglosar-cierta-cantidad-de-euros-en-billetes-y-monedas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre resolverlo con esto...

```
 private void textBox1__TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                label7.Text = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                int c1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                int Ctotalc1 = c1 * 1000;
                label7.Text = Ctotalc1.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Muchas gracias a todos por responder

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cambiar la condicional `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox14.Text)` eliminando el operador de negación `!` de la siguiente manera.

```
private void textBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int c1, Ctotalc1 = 0;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox14.Text)) c1 = 0;
  else c1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox14.Text);
  Ctotalc1 = c1 * 1000;
  lbt1000.Text = Ctotalc1.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo quite pero igual sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Bueno aunque no me di cuenta, el otro problema es el que señala @gbianchi
estas aplicando el evento al control equivocado, deberías aplicarlo al control `textBox14` edito mi respuesta para representarlo mejor,pero eso no basta, tendrás que en tu proyecto asignar este procedimiento de evento al control `textBox14`. `textBox14` es el control donde el usuario introduce los datos, es desde este control desde donde deben generarse los cambios hacia los demás, eso es elemental, hay que entenderlo, sino no lograras avanzar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple es hacerlo con un `DataGridView`, colocas uno en el Form. Luego creas una clase `Billete`

```
public class Billete
{
    public int Denominacion { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Total => Denominacion * Cantidad;
}
```

Y enlazas una `BindingList` al `DataGridView`

```
public BindingList<Billete> consolaList = new BindingList<Billete>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = consolaList;
}
```

Código completo

```js
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public BindingList<Billete> consolaList = new BindingList<Billete>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = consolaList;
    }
}
public class Billete
{
    public int Denominacion { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Total => Denominacion * Cantidad;
}
```

Y te debería quedar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]